# JMeter for database load testing

Tags: sql, jmeter, load-testing

I'm trying to use Apache JMeter to perform a database load test using a list of pre-generated SQL statements from a file.  The pre-generated SQL statements are various stored procedures that were captured from a trace so they have the needed values for the parameters as part of the execution statement.

I'm following the same design as a load test for an [`HTTP Request`](http://www.roman10.net/2012/07/28/apache-jmeter-input-from-file-with-http-testing-as-an-example/)
from an external file by setting the variable from the CSV_Data_Set_Config as the `PATH` value of the `HTTP Request` but replacing the `HTTP Request` with the `JDBC Request` and putting the variable from the CSV_Data_Set_Config for the SQL statement.  Each [example](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) I've seen only takes the contents of the file as variables into a predefined SQL statement but nothing takes each line from the file as a complete statement to execute.

In addition to using the CSV_Data_Set_Config I've tried going another route by trying to read lines from the file using the `CSVRead` function and putting the statement in the parameter values of the `JDBC Request` and using the `?` to fill in the SQL Statement at runtime however it seems to cut off the line after the first **period** in the three part name.  For example a line would be `exec {database}.{owner}.{procedure}` and the request would only send in `exec {database}`

Can you use JMeter in this manner with the `JDBC Request` controller?

Comment: Can you explain > "it seems to cut off the line after the first "

Comment: @user7294900 I've added some more detail to that section.

Comment: Please post the exact SQL/JDBC call.